# Every 10 seconds Timer Tick event want to call when the method not called

Tags: c#, timer

Within my code i have a method `MyMethod()` that will periodically be called from the outside (normally ~6 secs).

But under some circumstances my method won't be called anymore (e.g. the user canceled the progress) and i don't have the possibility to check for this event.

Due to this fact i'd like to start a 10 seconds timer that will be fired when my method is **not** called within this time frame.

How and when can i start this timer?

Comment: Show timer's initialization and a method code

Comment: What a fantastic question, maybe you could provide some information?

Comment: MyMethod() -> this method will call every 6 seconds once from the terminal... sometimes this method will not becoz of connection problem.. I want to check call connectionProblem() method if the MyMethod() will not call...

Comment: @VikramBose: This is not a comment. Instead update the question with the information you gave within the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instantiate a new timer with a duration of 10 seconds.
- Within `MyMethod()` simply call `myTimer.Stop()` and `myTimer.Start()`.

Every time you hit your method the timer will be reset and if the method is not called again within the ten seconds your timer will be fired.